# Subclass UICollectionViewCell not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to Swift, and I intend to programmatically create a `UICollectionView` with instances of a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. However, the cells themselves do not show up.

The majority of the following code is derived from this tutorial: [iOS Swift: Build UICollectionView programmatically without Storyboards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up-YD3rZeJA).

This is how I create the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let productView = ProductView(collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
productView.setSizeOfCollectionView(width, height: (height * 0.7))
middleLeftView.addSubview(productView.view)
```

And these are my subclasses:

```
class ProductView : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let customCellIdentifier = "customCellIdentifier"
    var products = [[String]]()
    var product1 = ["beer", "2,50"]
    var product2 = ["wine", "3,50"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        products.append(product1)
        products.append(product2)
        collectionView?.registerClass(Product.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let product = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(customCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Product
        product.specifiyProduct(products[indexPath.item])
        product.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        return product
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(products.count) // prints 2
        return products.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(300, 300)
    }

    func setSizeOfCollectionView(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
        print(width) // prints 1022.5
        print(height) // prints 702.8
        collectionView?.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, (width - 20), (height - 20))
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}
class Product : UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func specifiyProduct(info: [String]){
        let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        nameLabel.text = info[0] + info[1]
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v0]|" , options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[v0]|" , options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
    }

}
```

The `UICollectionView` shows up, but the `UICollectionViewCells` do not. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Where have you created the cell, in storyboard or in a xib file?

Comment: You also need to do contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change 
`collectionView?.registerClass(Product.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)`

with

`collectionView?.register(Product.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)`

The method you use to register cell has been renamed to the later one. That's might be the cause.